# Rendering safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having a problem with rendering in safari.

On firefox, chrome and IE. as you can see from the images below:
[image]

[image]

```css
input.searchbox{-webkit-border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;background-color:#af5354;border:1px solid #af5354;background-color:#AF5354;border:1px solid #AF5354;border-radius:5px;color:#FFF;float:left;height:19px;margin-left:0.5em;margin-top:1.3em;outline:0px none;padding-left:0.5em;padding-top:0.4em;text-align:left;width:170px;}
input.searchbox:focus{background:#e87476;background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e87476 0%, #e87476 20%);background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e87476), color-stop(20%, #e87476));outline:0;color:#FFF;}
*::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#FFF;}
*:-moz-placeholder{color:#FFF;}
*::-moz-placeholder{color:#FFF;}
*:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#FFF;}
input.button{background:url("../../assets/images/sprite.png") -142px -7px;border:none;float:left;height:28px;margin:16px 0px 0px -28px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;width:38px;}
input.button:hover{background:url("../../assets/images/sprite.png") -142px -47px;border:none;float:left;height:28px;margin:16px 0px 0px -28px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;width:38px;}
input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:none;}
```

```html
<form id=header-search>
<input class=searchbox placeholder="Search Spout TV">
<input type=submit class=button value=""/>
</form>
```

any way on how to fix it so it renders exact in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Add This:
input.searchbox{border-radius:10px;}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the border-radius without prefix to your input.searchbox.

Just add

```
input.searchbox {border-radius: 10px;}
```

To your css, and youre good to go.

You can also try using browser-specific CSS. For mozilla, it is:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.container {
    top: 00px;
    }
}
```

You can see a full list of browserhacks on http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: that isnt working either.
Here is the url: www.spouttv.com/spout/index.php
If you look at it in safari and in chrome, firefox or IE, you will see the button in the search is different in safari compared to the others.